# Is possible to build a Github action that will trigger when a PR is opened, and create an 'undo PR‘？

Tags: github, github-actions

I am trying to make a backup PR for my repo when there is new PR merged.

Is this possible to do it with GitHub actions?

Also, could it be a stand alone app/repo to manage other repos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would probably only create a revert PR only after the initial PR was merged, otherwise you could run into all kinds of issues.

This can definitely be implemented via GitHub Actions, by getting triggered by a PR merged trigger and checking the added commits in the initial PR and creating a revert for them back to whatever the base branch was before.

Still, GitHub is already able to do this natively with a click of a button in a PR, so I'm not sure what need this would fill.

See [GitHub Docs: Reverting a pull request](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/incorporating-changes-from-a-pull-request/reverting-a-pull-request)

Comment: After I tried, I fully agree with you. There is no need for a backup.