# Can GitHub action triggered by revert a pr?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am using GitHub actions to automatically build my app.
It will build when there is a PR closed and merged.

If I revert the change for my previous PR, does GitHub actions will trigger and rebuild my app?

I couldn't find any information from the GitHub Actions docs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is possible to build a Github action that will trigger when a PR is opened, and create an 'undo PR‘？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71863226/is-possible-to-build-a-github-action-that-will-trigger-when-a-pr-is-opened-and)